# converting hex into binary in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have to read a raw data from MODbus apps and convert it into hex. In the MODbus, it  displays in binary and hex. Lets say I want to read 5 bits = `00011` and when i have converted it to hex it become 0x03 but then when I convert it from hex to binary again. It displays in my UI like this = `11` only, which the 3 remaining zero `000` is disappear. This is my coding:

```
if (my_arguments.num_of_points <=8) 
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        block33.append(block22[9+x]);
    }
}

hexVal = block33.toHex(); //for converting to binary
stringValue = "0x " + block33.toHex().toUpper();  //display hex raw value

QString hexadecimalNumber = hexVal;

bool ok = false;

QString binaryNumber = QString::number(hexadecimalNumber.toLongLong(&ok, 16),2);

ui->textEdit->append(binaryNumber);

ui->textEdit->setText("RawValue in Hex = " + hex_rawValue );
```

Output =

```
  RawValue in Hex = 03

   11                  //but i read 5 bits so it should show `00011
```

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: If you intend to output a binary number (as text) with a fixed amount of digits, you should probably apply some kind of formatting...

Comment: Please ask a question, and provide a minimum, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what is `block33`?

Comment: @Scheff i want to display 00011 instead of 11 only,,because i read 5 bits

Comment: @Nic alright next time i will refer the given link.tq

Comment: Have a look at the answer: It's exactly what I recommended: "apply some kind of formatting".

Comment: @Scheff yes,, thankyou

Comment: @eyllanesc it just a `Qstring` variable.

Comment: @Scheff I am actually dont want a fixed amount of digits. what i need is that,, the binary number follows exactly what the bits i request. sometime when the last bit is `0` then it will not display the last bit with zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the QString::arg() overload instead of QString::number(). It has a *fieldWidth* argument that you can use to fill in the added zeros:

```
bool ok;
QString hexString = "0x03";
qDebug() << "BINARY 1: " << QString::number(hexString.toLongLong(&ok, 16),2);
qDebug() << "BINARY 2: " << QString("%1").arg(hexString.toULongLong(&ok, 16), 5, 2, QChar('0'));
```

Output is:

```
BINARY 1:  "11"
BINARY 2:  "00011"
```

So from the documentation on [QString::arg()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-1):

> QString QString::arg(qulonglong a, int fieldWidth = 0, int base = 10, QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' )) const
>
> fieldWidth specifies the minimum amount of space that a is padded to and filled with the character fillChar. A positive value produces right-aligned text; a negative value produces left-aligned text.
>
> The base argument specifies the base to use when converting the integer a into a string. base must be between 2 and 36, with 8 giving octal, 10 decimal, and 16 hexadecimal numbers.
>
> If fillChar is '0' (the number 0, ASCII 48), the locale's zero is used. For negative numbers, zero padding might appear before the minus sign.

Thus

1. The `5` states that the resulting string should have at least 5 characters.
2. The `2` states that the base of the output should be 2 (binary)
3. The `QChar('0')` states that if the result has less than 5 characters, pad `0` characters until there are 5 characters in the resulting string.

Since the 5 is positive, the `0` characters are added to the front. If it was -5 (negative) the characters would be padded at the back.

If for example you have 10 bits, given the above, no padding will be done since it is more than the 5 specified.

Comment: yes I got it. TQ !  but what is the function of `QChar('0')` there? aswell as 5, 2,? sorry I am a newbies in qt

Comment: sory,,but the 5 bits i just give as example,,can u please help me if i want to read any bits that i want?

Comment: for the code u gave above,when i try to read 7 bits,an error occur, n the apps exit itself

Comment: @raehee please see my edit to see if that answers your questions. Regarding your issue with 7 bits and an error, the string code should not cause the app to exit, something else might be wrong.

Comment: i have delete the given error.From the code that u gave, it is successful for up to 8bits, it give the correct binary,but if i want it read for 9 bits,, it give this values `10010000000001` which it is supposed to be `100100100`

Comment: @raehee My guess is that you have another bug in your code then

Comment: i think i encounter the same problem. lets say the 7bits is `0100100`. and then i use the code u gave to me. but it display `100100`. it does not read the zero. but if I make the 7 bits = `1100100`. Then it will display correctly `1100100`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is unclear after the [*accepted* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343255/7478597).

If it does not work in your case, something else has been done wrong. (This is what other commentors already told you.)

How could I convince you?

My last (desperate) try: a (not so) [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
  QString samples[] = {
    "0x0", "0x1", "0x1e", "0x11", "0x1111", "0x111e", "0x111f"
  };
  enum { n = sizeof samples / sizeof *samples };
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    const QString &hexString = samples[i];
    qDebug() << "Formatted binary output of " << hexString;
    for (int j = 1; j < 40; j += 8) {
      bool ok;
      qDebug()
        << QString("%1: %2")
        .arg(j, 2)
        .arg(hexString.toULongLong(&ok, 16), j, 2, QChar('0'));
    }
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested:

```
Formatted binary output of  "0x0"
" 1: 0"
" 9: 000000000"
"17: 00000000000000000"
"25: 0000000000000000000000000"
"33: 000000000000000000000000000000000"
Formatted binary output of  "0x1"
" 1: 1"
" 9: 000000001"
"17: 00000000000000001"
"25: 0000000000000000000000001"
"33: 000000000000000000000000000000001"
Formatted binary output of  "0x1e"
" 1: 11110"
" 9: 000011110"
"17: 00000000000011110"
"25: 0000000000000000000011110"
"33: 000000000000000000000000000011110"
Formatted binary output of  "0x11"
" 1: 10001"
" 9: 000010001"
"17: 00000000000010001"
"25: 0000000000000000000010001"
"33: 000000000000000000000000000010001"
Formatted binary output of  "0x1111"
" 1: 1000100010001"
" 9: 1000100010001"
"17: 00001000100010001"
"25: 0000000000001000100010001"
"33: 000000000000000000001000100010001"
Formatted binary output of  "0x111e"
" 1: 1000100011110"
" 9: 1000100011110"
"17: 00001000100011110"
"25: 0000000000001000100011110"
"33: 000000000000000000001000100011110"
Formatted binary output of  "0x111f"
" 1: 1000100011111"
" 9: 1000100011111"
"17: 00001000100011111"
"25: 0000000000001000100011111"
"33: 000000000000000000001000100011111"
```

Note:

The number before the colon (`:`) provides the used field width.

The sample output shows that the output might become longer if the resulting number cannot be displayed correctly with the amount of digits provided as field width.

This is exactly as described in the doc. (emphasizing by me):

> fieldWidth specifies the **minimum** amount of space that a is padded to

Comment: the accepted answer is exactly correct for a fixed bits. but I got the idea how to do it. Sorry a bit slow because I am a newbie. yeah TQ !